# Typed text fails to iterate through the array variable

Tags: javascript, html

the following javascript code fails to iterate through the **textArray** array and keeps on printing only the longest string i.e., **"a Technology"** for some reason.

```js
const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");

const textArray = ["a Technology", "a Science", "an Art"];
const typingDelay = 300;
const erasingDelay = 200;
const newTextDelay = 2500;
let textArrayIndex = 0;
let charIndex = 0;

function type() {
    if(charIndex<textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
        typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
        charIndex++;
        setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
    }
}

function erase() {
    if(charIndex>0) {
        typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex-1);
        charIndex--;
        setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
    }
    else {
        textArrayIndex++;
        if(textArrayIndex>=textArray.length) textArrayIndex=0;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("load", setInterval(type, newTextDelay + 250));
```

```html
<span class="typed-text"></span>
```

I would very much appreciate if someone can help me through this.

Comment: are you trying to achieve effect of displaying text char by char, erasing it char by char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your `setInterval` was being fired before the text could be wiped, and because of this, `textArrayIntex` was still in the same index when the second and other times `setInterval` was firing.

```html
<span class="typed-text"></span>

<script>

  const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");

  const textArray = ["a Technology", "a Science", "an Art"];
  const typingDelay = 100;
  const erasingDelay = 50;
  const newTextDelay = 1000;
  let textArrayIndex = 0;
  let charIndex = 0;

  function type() {
    if (charIndex < textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
      typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
      charIndex++;
      setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
    }
  }

  function erase() {
    if (charIndex > 0) {
      typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1);
      charIndex--;
      setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
    }

    else {
      textArrayIndex++;
      if (textArrayIndex == textArray.length) textArrayIndex = 0;
      // Type next word, after updating textArrayIndex.
      type();
    }
  }

  window.onload = type;

</script>
```

Also fixed some minor bugs :) overall good code!

Also you should checkout the [Typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) library, it may help you make the "typing" animations easier and more customizable, here's an example:

```html
<p>This is <span class="typed"></span></p>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>

<script>
  // For more examples check: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js
  // Full docs at: https://mattboldt.github.io/typed.js/docs/
  const options = {
    strings: ["a Technology", "a Science", "an Art"],
    typeSpeed: 40,
    backSpeed: 40,
    backDelay: 2000,
    loop: true,
  };
  
  // We'll bind the typing animation to the .typed class.
  let typed = new Typed('.typed', options);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the respose. It now works as it should. And yes not to take someone’s credit,  this code ain’t mine, I just started html today and got this thing from youtube.